# wicket 1.5 filling up div content dynamically with another div(s)

Tags: java, wicket

Maybe it's an easy question, but I'm new to wicket and after googling for some time I can't find the answer.

Let's assume I have a div, a container, where I store some data.

```
<div id="container">
    [here goes data]
</div>
```

Now I connect to a database where I have some number (we dont know how many) messages to display with a date. The thing is I want the cointainer to be popullated with yet another divs for example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="first-message>
        <span>15.11.2011</span>
        <span>A message</span>
    </div>
    <div id="second-message>
        <span>14.11.2011</span>
        <span>A message</span>
    </div>
    <div id="third-message>
        <span>13.11.2011</span>
        <span>A message</span>
    </div>
    ...and so on...
</div>
```

Is it possible? Where should I look for answer? One think that upsets me is lack of good support for wicket newbies :/

Comment: You would do well to read one of the Wicket text books. 'Wicket In Action' is good. There are others. Also make sure you have the Wicket source code installed. It's invaluable for tracing what's happening when things don't seem to be working. Having said that, once you get the hang of things, Wicket is a really nice framework to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is a subclass of `AbstractRepeater`. Have a look at `ListView` and its javadoc for a start. A repeater repeats its markup multiple times. Your html would look like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div wicket:id="repeater">
      <span wicket:id="date">15.11.2011</span>
      <span wicket:id="message">A message</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Java, the repeater would be added with the id `repeater`. Each repeater child item would contain both `date` and `message` `labels`.

Some reference material for you:

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/listview-and-other-repeaters.html

http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/guestbook.html

http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.CheckGroupPage

Answer (score 2):

you could use ListView 
take a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/listview-and-other-repeaters.html
 for support you can also see at 
http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/index.html